# Nested Laravel Project Nginx Config

Tags: php, nginx, laravel

We are introducing a new section on our website which uses the Laravel framework. It is placed in a sub-directory, for example `/newsection`. How should I configure the nginx.conf without making any conflicts with my previous rewrite rules.

This is my current `nginx.conf`

```
    server {
        listen  80;
        server_name  localhost www.website.com;
        root  /home/www/website;
        index  index.html index.php;

        location /newsection/ { 
           rewrite ^/ /newsection/public/index.php last;  
           # this is my attempt at it
        }

         location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
         }

         location /php-status {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
         }


         location @rewrite {
            rewrite  ^/([\w_-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
            rewrite  ^/([\w_-]+)/([\w_-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&slug=$2 last;
            rewrite  ^/([\w_-]+)/([\w_-]+)/([\w_-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&slug=$2&pagination=$3 last;
          }

        include php.conf;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it works like most frameworks I know work, this should work

```
location /newsection/ { 
   try_files $uri $uri/ /newsection/public/index.php$request_uri;
}
```

If this returns 404 try removing the extra `/newsection` in the fallback URI of the `try_files`

Comment: I was not patient and decided to go for a subdomain solution. When I find time I will test your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for laravelin subdirectories

```
location ^~ /laravel {
alias /var/www/laravel/public;
try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;

location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
}


location @laravel {
    rewrite /laravel/(.*)$ /laravel/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```